# How to pass function from statefull to stateless component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass the function from stateful component to stateless component below is my code.

below is stateless code

```
const ProductsGridItem = props => {
const { result } = props;
const source = result._source;  
return (
<ProductCard
  ProductName={source.productName}
  ProductGuid={source.productGuid}
  Key={source.productGuid}
  ProductStatus={source.status}
  DecimalPrecision={decimalValue}
  IsActive={source.isActive}
  Image={source.imageName}
  ProductCode={source.productCode}
  MinPrice={source.minPrice}
  Ratings={source.ratings}
  CurrencySymbol={source.currencySymbol}
  SupplierGuid={source.supplierGuid}
  Type="grid"
  ListBucketDetails={basketDetails}
  WishListDetails={wishListDetails}
  CompanyName={source.companyName}
  BuyingWindowStatus={source["buyingwindowstatus.raw"]}
  NewArrival={source["newarrival_raw.raw"]}
 />
);
};
```

and below this my class method starts that is stateful code starts.

```
 class ProductListingPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      resources: [],
      isFeatureAvailable: false,
      loading: false,
      decimalPrecesion: "",
      filterList: [],
      productBucketList: [],
      open: false,
      rating: 1,
      companyGuid: null,
      showMobileFilter: false,
      dataEmpty: false

    };
  }
  handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };
}
```

I want to pass the `handleDrawerOpen` in `ProductCard` component. Could you please help how to do this?

I can fix this issue by moving `const ProductsGridItem` in `class` but my seniors not allowing me to do this. I dont know why. Both code are in same file. Please help.

EDITED:
In render the stateless component is using like below

```
 <ViewSwitcherHits
                      hitsPerPage={16}
                      sourceFilter={[
                        "productName",
                        "productCode",
                        "imageName",
                        "manufacturerName",
                        "productGuid",
                        "tagAttributes",
                        "status",
                        "isActive",
                        "minPrice",
                        "ratings",
                        "currencySymbol",
                        "supplierGuid",
                        "companyName",
                        "buyingwindowstatus.raw",
                        "listproductsubcategory",
                        "newarrival_raw.raw"
                      ]}
                      hitComponents={[
                        {
                          key: "grid",
                          title: getLabelText(
                            resources.filter(x => {
                              return x.resourceKey === "grid";
                            })[0],
                            "Grid"
                          ),
                          itemComponent: ProductsGridItem,
                          InitialLoaderComponent: InitialLoaderComponent,
                          defaultOption: true
                        },
                        {
                          key: "list",
                          title: getLabelText(
                            resources.filter(x => {
                              return x.resourceKey === "list";
                            })[0],
                            "List"
                          ),
                          itemComponent: ProductsListItem,
                          InitialLoaderComponent: InitialLoaderComponent
                        }
                      ]}
                      scrollTo="body"
                    />
```

**In Hitcomponents - itemComponent: ProductsGridItem,** I'm using `Searchkit ViewSwitcherHits`

Comment: Have you tried passing it as a prop?

Comment: yes. this.props.handleDrawerOpen. But there is no handleDraweropen in props when I console the props

Comment: That might be because the context is being lost. Try passing with binded context

Comment: You have to pass it from the parent, inside it's render function where you render `ProductsGridItem`: `<ProductsGridItem onDrawerOpen={this.handleDrawerOpen}`

Comment: @Rajesh - It's an arrow function, no need for binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `ProductListingPage`'s `render` (which you haven't shown) uses `ProductsGridItem`. In that location, you'd pass `this.handleOpen`:

```
<ProductsGridItem handleOpen={this.handleOpen} YourOtherStuffHere />
```

Within `ProductsGridItem`, you'd pass that on to `ProductsGrid`:

```
return (
  <ProductCard
    handleOpen={props.handleOpen}
    YourOtherStuffHere
  />
);
```

---

Some style rules suggest not using `props.` within the JSX for child components. If your in-house style rules say not to do that, you can put `handleOpen` in an initial destructuring of `props`:

```
const ProductsGridItem = props => {
  const { result: {_source: source}, handleOpen } = props;
  return (
    <ProductCard
      handleOpen={handleOpen}
      ProductName={source.productName}
      ProductGuid={source.productGuid}
      Key={source.productGuid}
      ProductStatus={source.status}
      DecimalPrecision={decimalValue}
      IsActive={source.isActive}
      Image={source.imageName}
      ProductCode={source.productCode}
      MinPrice={source.minPrice}
      Ratings={source.ratings}
      CurrencySymbol={source.currencySymbol}
      SupplierGuid={source.supplierGuid}
      Type="grid"
      ListBucketDetails={basketDetails}
      WishListDetails={wishListDetails}
      CompanyName={source.companyName}
      BuyingWindowStatus={source["buyingwindowstatus.raw"]}
      NewArrival={source["newarrival_raw.raw"]}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: sorry I have already passed props.handleDraweropen in ProductCard. Now worked. I checked the props in Productcard component where function handleOpen gives undefined

Comment: It worked. I replaced itemComponent: ProductsGridItem, to  itemComponent: <ProductsGridItem handleOpen={this.handleOpen} /> and It works. Thank you so much for help. I thought there was no < >  itemComponent: ProductsGridItem So it's not possible to pass the props.